# How to use a method that has a pointer to an array for an argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to make a method that has for argument a pointer to the first element of an array, and that then cycles through the array looking for something...

```
void MyClass::myMethod(T *x)
{
     // I know that *x points to the first entry in a properly defined array.
     // I want to cycle through this array, and try to find a member T of that array that
     // meets certain criteria.
     // I would then like to store a pointer to this T that meets my criteria.
}
```

Comment: How do you know how many elements are in the array? Perhaps the signature should be `void MyClass::myMethod(T* x, size_t n)`. Or better, use `void MyClass::myMethod(vector<T>& x)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you have problem with? Passing the argument? The "cycling" (also known as iterating or looping)? The checking for equality? Something else?

Comment: jww: Another module in my program will take care of creating the array of T I'm interested in, and will always supply me with an accurate size of the array. Joachim: I'm coming from Java, and am somewhat confused about how to use pointers effectively, and the differences in passing and using arrays...

Comment: @jww: rule of thumb: avoid referencing specific types of containers for algorithms. That's why half the stdlib uses iterators. They're container-agnostic, mostly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to pass the size of the array explicitly. Then you can do:

```
for(T *current = x; current < x + count; ++current) {
    // do something with current, compare or whatever
}
```

An alternative would be to use indexing notation, like below. Which one is better mainly depends on how exactly you want to access the data later on.

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // current element is x[i]
    // pointer to current element is then x+i, or &x[i]
}
```

Usually you are better off using standard array containers, implementing your algorithms using iterators. Your function then takes two iterators defining the range on which it should operate, basically like this:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void doSomething(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
         // current element is *begin
    }
}
```

Comment: And the best way I can achieve this is by just adding a second int argument?

Comment: Yes. Or by using standard containers, either by passing them directly (usually by reference), or by passing two iterators (start & end of the range you want to operate on).

Comment: The iterator approach will also work for C-Arrays since a pointer is a valid random access iterator. Depending on the situation it may also be appropriate to take an array by reference so `template<int N> void myMethod( const T (&x)[N] );`

Comment: Note that when using arrays as "forward iterators" you need to pass 'em like this: `doSomething(array, array + count)`. No +1 oder -1 involved - keep in mind, iterators are usually used for half-open intervals and *end is then not part of the data.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using pointers. Create a vector and use find_if to return the iterator(position ) of the element of interest and do your processing.